# Wait for image to be processed on S3 and then fade it in using Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave for Rails to process images. These images are using carrierwave_backgrounder to process the images on Amazon S3.

The issue is that once I save the entry, it redirects me back to the index view, which shows broken images, since they haven't been processed yet.

How would I go about implementing code that checks from the index view to see if the image has been processed, which I could then fade in?

carrierwave backgrounder does set a db column to null after processing, just not sure how to integrate that with jquery.

Any guidance would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Optionally you can add a column to the database which will be set to
>   nil when the background processing is complete.
>
> add_column :users, :avatar_processing, :boolean

/via [carrierwave_backgrounder doc](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder)

So, that you can place this flag on your rails view(for example, in data-attribute in img tag), and check it with jquery.